# Change function not initialized when the change occurred by Javascript itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input (number type) which I added increment and decrement buttons.

When the input's value changes, multiple span's values are changed on my modal.

If I click on the input field and press `up` and `down` arrow keys to change the value, the change function occurs ans the span's values are changed.

But if I use increment and decrement buttons, the input value changes but is not considered as a change, and the span's values stay the same. Is that because it is occured by a Javascript function itself ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
$(".modal").each(function(){

    var qtyInput = $(this).find("input");
    var qtyItemRecap = $(this).find(".quantity-item-recap");
    var itemPrice = parseInt($(this).find("#item-price").text());
    var itemGain = parseInt($(this).find("#item-gain").text());
    var totalPrice = $(this).find(".dragon-coin-total");
    var totalGain = $(this).find(".silver-coin-total");

    var lessBtn = $(this).find("#quantity-less-btn");
    var moreBtn = $(this).find("#quantity-more-btn");

    $(qtyInput).change(function(){

        var inputVal = parseInt($(this).val());

        qtyItemRecap.text(inputVal);
        totalPrice.text(itemPrice * inputVal);
        totalGain.text(itemGain * inputVal);
    });

    $(lessBtn.add(moreBtn)).click(function() {

        var $button = $(this);
        var oldValue = $button.parent().parent().find("input").val();

        if ($button.text() == "+") {
            var newVal = parseInt(oldValue) + 1;
        } else {
            if (oldValue > 1) {
                var newVal = parseInt(oldValue) - 1;
            } else {
                newVal = 1;
            }
        }

        $button.parent().parent().find("input").val(newVal);   
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont really understand your code but i think what you need is jquery trigger function.
Whenever you increment or decrement, just do

```
$(qtyInput).trigger('change');
```

the change event is triggered and then your event listeners can run